Funeral Rites vs. Funerary Rites
Are both of the following sentences correct?

The question then arises: what purpose do Hopi funeral rites serve?
He stilled, wondering how best to explain Kai funerary rites or ...

Thanks.

Both funeral rites and funerary rites are valid.  The funeral version  is much more common than the other one.
Similar usage pattern is seen in phrases with other nouns, which more likely follow funeral than the other one.

Funeral and funerary are related words but they are not identical. Consider these definitions from Merriam-Webster:

Funeral (adjective)


of, relating to, or constituting a funeral
(a funeral [noun] is defined as the observances held for a dead person usually before burial or cremation)


Funerary


of, used for, or associated with burial
Example: a pharaoh's funerary chamber

So although these words are related, there is a difference of scope. Funerary rituals are burial rituals. For example, funerary refers to the items buried with a pharaoh in a pyramid. Funeral rituals are death rituals. They may include the burial elements, but will also include such things as times of mourning or a funeral service prior to burial.

My great-grandfather resided in a funerary urn for years on a mantelpiece in my grandmother's house, in the form of ashes. It spooked me a bit as a kid, when my mother told me what that odd-shaped 'vase' contained. When Grandma died and the house was sold, nobody wanted them (!) and they were tipped rather unceremoniously into the river Trent, I gathered.

It's so hard to find a spare pyramid these days...

Thank you, Peter.
